# Nested if statement not retrieving values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ms-office

I have a nested if statement below as:

```
=IF(F2="Sunday","Weekend",IF(F2="Monday","Weekday",IF(F2="Tuesday","Weekday",IF(F2="Wenesday","Weekday",IF(F2="Thursday","Weekday",IF(F2="Friday","Weekend",IF(F2="Saturday","Weekend","NA")))))))
```

Where column has Sunday - Saturday text values, but it gives me NA for each cell not sure what I have incorrect? Thanks!

Comment: The formula works fine for me I do however note you have spelled Wednesday wrong.

Comment: My guess without seeing the data is the text is actually a date that is formatted to show the day of the week and not the actual text. Or you have spaces in the data.

Comment: Yes the Actual day of week column is a date formatted to show day of week

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When referencing a cell, Excel uses the data stored and not what is shown.  So a date that if formatted to show `dddd` is still the date and not the name of the day shown.  That is an advantage in this case as we can use `WEEKDAY()` on the date, regardless how it is formatted.

Use

```
=IF(WEEKDAY(F2,2)<6,"Weekday","Weekend")
```

[image]

Comment: In your original post you stated the day was text values, if it's a date this completely changes things and @Scott Craner answer will do what you need. Note the reason it was always NA was because it was never a day in text so it never hit the criteria, it was actually a number which represents a date.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to work fine for me.  Make sure you spell Wednesday properly.
[image]

Comment: My Day column is date formatted to show day of week, how can I change this to text?

Comment: Right click F:F column > Format Cells... and select general.  If you are using a formatted Date try changing the output to text.  Without knowing more about how your date is generated, it is hard to tell you exactly, but your formula works on text input

Comment: yes this answer was based on the fact that the original question indicated the weekday was text input.  If it is date then the accepted answer should definitely be the accepted answer, but this answer was provided based on the actual criteria in the question